# how to save plt plot obtained from netCDF4 as georeferenced geoTiff?

Tags: matplotlib, gdal, matplotlib-basemap, netcdf4

Below code is taken from http://www.acgeospatial.co.uk/sentinel-5p-and-python/
This is a very nice tutorial on how to process with Sentinel 5p netCDF data.
Now I tried to save obtained plt image as georeferenced Tiff (geoTiff). How to do this?

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from netCDF4 import Dataset
import numpy as np  

file = 'S5P_OFFL_L2__O3_____20201025T093552_20201025T111721_15720_01_020103_20201027T030032.nc'
fh = Dataset(file, mode='r')

  
lons = fh.groups['PRODUCT'].variables['longitude'][:][0,:,:]
lats = fh.groups['PRODUCT'].variables['latitude'][:][0,:,:]
o3 = fh.groups['PRODUCT'].variables['ozone_total_vertical_column'][0,:,:]
o3_units = fh.groups['PRODUCT'].variables['ozone_total_vertical_column_precision'].units
#o3_units = o3_units

m = Basemap(width=5000000,height=3500000,\
            llcrnrlon=-15.,llcrnrlat=30.,urcrnrlon=80.,urcrnrlat=80.,\
            resolution='c',projection='merc',\
            #lat_ts=40,lat_0=lat_0,lon_0=lon_0)
            lat_ts=40,lat_0=50,lon_0=20)

xi, yi = m(lons, lats)

# Plot Data
cs = m.pcolor(xi,yi,np.squeeze(o3*2241.15), cmap='jet')

#plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

As you see the result is presented with plt.show metod. But I would like to save it to geoTiff. Thanks!

Comment: I have not used [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/323317/converting-netcdf-dataset-array-to-geotiff-using-rasterio-python/329141#329141) and [this](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/profiles.html) from long time but i was working great with python2.

Comment: Thanks @JayPatel, but I don't know how to implement this to the code above... my image is stored in cs variable right? so how to proceed further..  :/